# 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 17: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-imaging-library

'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 17: invalid continuation byte
it didn't happen on my windows but occur on server when it uploads image to imagefield model

Tried:`# -*- coding: utf8 -*-` on first line of every file
mysql 5.1.30
django 1.6.3
I'm kind of stuck here. Can anyone help?

Comment: The PEP 263 `coding` comment only applies to your *source code*, not to any other (implicit) encoding or decoding; adding it everywhere won't magically make your unicode problems go away. Show us your code, with the full traceback.

Comment: check if you happen to render non unicode text. For example in a template tag returning `"<div>text</div>"`, a fix would be to return `u"<div..."`